# Who is the new girl in Kirino's group?

Tags: oreimo

In the last episode of *Ore no Imouto ga Konna ni Kawaii Wake ga Nai*, there's one new member in Kirino's group: Otaku Girls Unite, and she seems to be somewhat important.

I know that this anime is already ending just like the light novel, and there won't be any further episodes. But I've been wondering, who is this new girl? Maybe they show it in the light novel?

Comment: Do you have a screenshot?

Comment: no picture of her, Kirino only said that there's a new member in their group

Comment: I think it is only to show that she makes more otaku friends, with whom she can be her-otaku-self.

Comment: Or it could be one of Kirino's friend as well or even Kuroneko little sister, afterwards his brother is also part of the group.

Comment: I personally think that it could be Ayase since she gradually accept Kirino's hobby on otaku

Answer (score 3):

The new girl is never shown in the novel, manga or anime. The new character is not important either, it just goes to show that Saori found another person to join their group and things are going well in the otaku circle. Also, they never said that it was a girl, they just said a new member is joining.
To your opinion of Ayase joining, it could be but it would be very unlikely because

1. Even though Ayase did say that she will allow Kirino to keep playing eroge, but to my memory, she did say that one day she will save Kirino from eroges and that she'll never play something as lewd as that.
2. If Ayase was joing the otaku circle, you would think that Kirino would know about it since they are really good friends.
3. Kuroneko's relationship isn't very good with Ayase.

Those are just my opinions though and I can't comment them.

Comment: In the novels, Kuroneko and Ayase actually develop a very "special" relationship towards the end, in one of the weirder moments of the series. I agree it's unlikely that Ayase is joining the group, though; I think you're right that the new girl is just mentioned to show that things are going well for Saori's otaku circle and they're recruiting new members.